# a.class and class.a ( regarding styling a link) What is the diffidence in CSS

Tags: css

Please see below two, Could anyone explain to me the difference  a.class and class.a:

```
.MyClass a:link, .MyClass a:visited {
color:red;
}


a.MyClass :link, a.MyClass :visited {
color:green;
}
```

Comment: Check this [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: DON'T REPOST THE SAME QUESTION! if it's not a duplicate then edit the first one and explain why you tink it's not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041348/what-are-the-difference-between-these-two-css-class-to-a-link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`a.class` refers to a `a` tag (link) which has the class `class`.
`.class a` refers to a `a` tag inside any tag which has the class `class`.

```
<div class="class">
   <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

```
<a class="class">Link</a>
```

```
.class a {
  // This will affect the first chunk
}

a.class {
  // This will affect the second chunk
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!